# how to set placeholder for country select javascript dropdown

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using mrmarkfrench countryselect.js library from github to get country list in my form input. everything works perfectly but here i want placeholder for input type, because by default it shows united states.

i dont want any country selected by default. i want users to promt if they dont select this input by making input field required.  how to set placeholders here. anyhelp, it will be thankful.

```
<input type="text" id="country" class="textBoxDashed">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/countrySelect.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#country").countrySelect();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Forgot that OP requests that `required` attribute works. Now it works flawlessly.

A. This procedure involves a minor modification in the plugin:

1. Open an ***unminified*** copy of **countrySelect.js** (***not countrySelect.min.js***)
2. Scroll down to the bottom of the source and add this to the end of the country list:

   ```
   , {
       n: "",
       i: "xx"
   }
   ```
3. Save the file.

B. Next, add the following script before the `</body>` end tag:

```
$("#country").countrySelect({
    preferredCountries: ["xx"]
  });

  blankFlag.call(this);

  $("#country").on('change', blankFlag);

  function blankFlag(e) {
    if ($('.flag').hasClass('xx')) {

      $('.xx').addClass('blank');

     } else {

       return false;
     }
  }
```

C. Then in the markup, add this to the `<input>` tag:

```
placeholder="Select Country"
```

D. Last step is to add the CSS that's in the demo below.

What we are doing is placing a placeholder element in the script, then setting it as the **preferredCountries** option, then use a small white gif as the flag image and a transparent gif for `:hover`.

### Demo

*the modified plugin is minified*

```js
$("#country").countrySelect({
    preferredCountries: ["xx"]
  });

  blankFlag.call(this);

  $("#country").on('change', blankFlag);

  function blankFlag(e) {
    if ($('.flag').hasClass('xx')) {

      $('.xx').addClass('blank');

     } else {
     
       return false;
     }
  }
```

```css
.flag.xx.xx.blank.blank {
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=)round;
  background-size: cover;
}

.flag.xx.xx.blank.blank:hover {
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==)round;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/country-select-js/2.0.1/css/countrySelect.min.css" />


<form>
  <input type="text" id="country" class="textBoxDashed" required placeholder='Select Country'>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--BEGIN MODIFIED SCRIPT---------------------------->
<script>
!function(n){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],function(i){n(i,window,document)}):n(jQuery,window,document)}(function(n,i,t,a){"use strict";function e(i,t){this.element=i,this.options=n.extend({},r,t),this._defaults=r,this.ns="."+s+o++,this._name=s,this.init()}var s="countrySelect",o=1,r={defaultCountry:"",defaultStyling:"inside",excludeCountries:[],onlyCountries:[],preferredCountries:["us","gb"]},u={UP:38,DOWN:40,ENTER:13,ESC:27,PLUS:43,A:65,Z:90},l=!1;n(i).on("load",function(){l=!0}),e.prototype={init:function(){return this._processCountryData(),this._generateMarkup(),this._setInitialState(),this._initListeners(),this.autoCountryDeferred=new n.Deferred,this._initAutoCountry(),this.autoCountryDeferred},_processCountryData:function(){this._setInstanceCountryData(),this._setPreferredCountries()},_setInstanceCountryData:function(){var i=this;if(this.options.onlyCountries.length){var t=[];n.each(this.options.onlyCountries,function(n,a){var e=i._getCountryData(a,!0);e&&t.push(e)}),this.countries=t}else if(this.options.excludeCountries.length){var a=this.options.excludeCountries.map(function(n){return n.toLowerCase()});this.countries=h.filter(function(n){return-1===a.indexOf(n.iso2)})}else this.countries=h},_setPreferredCountries:function(){var i=this;this.preferredCountries=[],n.each(this.options.preferredCountries,function(n,t){var a=i._getCountryData(t,!1);a&&i.preferredCountries.push(a)})},_generateMarkup:function(){this.countryInput=n(this.element);var i="country-select";this.options.defaultStyling&&(i+=" "+this.options.defaultStyling),this.countryInput.wrap(n("<div>",{class:i}));var t=n("<div>",{class:"flag-dropdown"}).insertAfter(this.countryInput),a=n("<div>",{class:"selected-flag"}).appendTo(t);this.selectedFlagInner=n("<div>",{class:"flag"}).appendTo(a),n("<div>",{class:"arrow"}).appendTo(a),this.countryList=n("<ul>",{class:"country-list v-hide"}).appendTo(t),this.preferredCountries.length&&(this._appendListItems(this.preferredCountries,"preferred"),n("<li>",{class:"divider"}).appendTo(this.countryList)),this._appendListItems(this.countries,""),this.countryCodeInput=n("#"+this.countryInput.attr("id")+"_code"),this.countryCodeInput||(this.countryCodeInput=n('<input type="hidden" id="'+this.countryInput.attr("id")+'_code" name="'+this.countryInput.attr("name")+'_code" value="" />'),this.countryCodeInput.insertAfter(this.countryInput)),this.dropdownHeight=this.countryList.outerHeight(),this.countryList.removeClass("v-hide").addClass("hide"),this.countryListItems=this.countryList.children(".country")},_appendListItems:function(i,t){var a="";n.each(i,function(n,i){a+='<li class="country '+t+'" data-country-code="'+i.iso2+'">',a+='<div class="flag '+i.iso2+'"></div>',a+='<span class="country-name">'+i.name+"</span>",a+="</li>"}),this.countryList.append(a)},_setInitialState:function(){var n=!1;this.countryInput.val()&&(n=this._updateFlagFromInputVal());var i=this.countryCodeInput.val();if(i&&this.selectCountry(i),!n){var t;this.options.defaultCountry?(t=this._getCountryData(this.options.defaultCountry,!1))||(t=this.preferredCountries.length?this.preferredCountries[0]:this.countries[0]):t=this.preferredCountries.length?this.preferredCountries[0]:this.countries[0],this.defaultCountry=t.iso2}},_initListeners:function(){var n=this;this.countryInput.on("keyup"+this.ns,function(){n._updateFlagFromInputVal()}),this.selectedFlagInner.parent().on("click"+this.ns,function(i){n.countryList.hasClass("hide")&&!n.countryInput.prop("disabled")&&n._showDropdown()}),this.countryInput.on("blur"+this.ns,function(){n.countryInput.val()!=n.getSelectedCountryData().name&&n.setCountry(n.countryInput.val()),n.countryInput.val(n.getSelectedCountryData().name)})},_initAutoCountry:function(){"auto"===this.options.initialCountry?this._loadAutoCountry():(this.selectCountry(this.defaultCountry),this.autoCountryDeferred.resolve())},_loadAutoCountry:function(){n.fn[s].autoCountry?this.handleAutoCountry():n.fn[s].startedLoadingAutoCountry||(n.fn[s].startedLoadingAutoCountry=!0,"function"==typeof this.options.geoIpLookup&&this.options.geoIpLookup(function(i){n.fn[s].autoCountry=i.toLowerCase(),setTimeout(function(){n(".country-select input").countrySelect("handleAutoCountry")})}))},_focus:function(){this.countryInput.focus();var n=this.countryInput[0];if(n.setSelectionRange){var i=this.countryInput.val().length;n.setSelectionRange(i,i)}},_showDropdown:function(){this._setDropdownPosition();var n=this.countryList.children(".active");this._highlightListItem(n),this.countryList.removeClass("hide"),this._scrollTo(n),this._bindDropdownListeners(),this.selectedFlagInner.parent().children(".arrow").addClass("up")},_setDropdownPosition:function(){var t=this.countryInput.offset().top,a=n(i).scrollTop(),e=t+this.countryInput.outerHeight()+this.dropdownHeight<a+n(i).height(),s=t-this.dropdownHeight>a,o=!e&&s?"-"+(this.dropdownHeight-1)+"px":"";this.countryList.css("top",o)},_bindDropdownListeners:function(){var i=this;this.countryList.on("mouseover"+this.ns,".country",function(t){i._highlightListItem(n(this))}),this.countryList.on("click"+this.ns,".country",function(t){i._selectListItem(n(this))});var a=!0;n("html").on("click"+this.ns,function(n){a||i._closeDropdown(),a=!1}),n(t).on("keydown"+this.ns,function(n){n.preventDefault(),n.which==u.UP||n.which==u.DOWN?i._handleUpDownKey(n.which):n.which==u.ENTER?i._handleEnterKey():n.which==u.ESC?i._closeDropdown():n.which>=u.A&&n.which<=u.Z&&i._handleLetterKey(n.which)})},_handleUpDownKey:function(n){var i=this.countryList.children(".highlight").first(),t=n==u.UP?i.prev():i.next();t.length&&(t.hasClass("divider")&&(t=n==u.UP?t.prev():t.next()),this._highlightListItem(t),this._scrollTo(t))},_handleEnterKey:function(){var n=this.countryList.children(".highlight").first();n.length&&this._selectListItem(n)},_handleLetterKey:function(i){var t=String.fromCharCode(i),a=this.countryListItems.filter(function(){return n(this).text().charAt(0)==t&&!n(this).hasClass("preferred")});if(a.length){var e,s=a.filter(".highlight").first();e=s&&s.next()&&s.next().text().charAt(0)==t?s.next():a.first(),this._highlightListItem(e),this._scrollTo(e)}},_updateFlagFromInputVal:function(){var i=this,t=this.countryInput.val().replace(/(?=[() ])/g,"\\");if(t){for(var a=[],e=new RegExp("^"+t,"i"),s=0;s<this.countries.length;s++)this.countries[s].name.match(e)&&a.push(this.countries[s].iso2);var o=!1;return n.each(a,function(n,t){i.selectedFlagInner.hasClass(t)&&(o=!0)}),o||(this._selectFlag(a[0]),this.countryCodeInput.val(a[0]).trigger("change")),!0}return!1},_highlightListItem:function(n){this.countryListItems.removeClass("highlight"),n.addClass("highlight")},_getCountryData:function(n,i){for(var t=i?h:this.countries,a=0;a<t.length;a++)if(t[a].iso2==n)return t[a];return null},_selectFlag:function(n){if(!n)return!1;this.selectedFlagInner.attr("class","flag "+n);var i=this._getCountryData(n);this.selectedFlagInner.parent().attr("title",i.name);var t=this.countryListItems.children(".flag."+n).first().parent();this.countryListItems.removeClass("active"),t.addClass("active")},_selectListItem:function(n){var i=n.attr("data-country-code");this._selectFlag(i),this._closeDropdown(),this._updateName(i),this.countryInput.trigger("change"),this.countryCodeInput.trigger("change"),this._focus()},_closeDropdown:function(){this.countryList.addClass("hide"),this.selectedFlagInner.parent().children(".arrow").removeClass("up"),n(t).off("keydown"+this.ns),n("html").off("click"+this.ns),this.countryList.off(this.ns)},_scrollTo:function(n){if(n&&n.offset()){var i=this.countryList,t=i.height(),a=i.offset().top,e=a+t,s=n.outerHeight(),o=n.offset().top,r=o+s,u=o-a+i.scrollTop();if(o<a)i.scrollTop(u);else if(r>e){var l=t-s;i.scrollTop(u-l)}}},_updateName:function(n){this.countryCodeInput.val(n).trigger("change"),this.countryInput.val(this._getCountryData(n).name)},handleAutoCountry:function(){"auto"===this.options.initialCountry&&(this.defaultCountry=n.fn[s].autoCountry,this.countryInput.val()||this.selectCountry(this.defaultCountry),this.autoCountryDeferred.resolve())},getSelectedCountryData:function(){var n=this.selectedFlagInner.attr("class").split(" ")[1];return this._getCountryData(n)},selectCountry:function(n){n=n.toLowerCase(),this.selectedFlagInner.hasClass(n)||(this._selectFlag(n),this._updateName(n))},setCountry:function(n){this.countryInput.val(n),this._updateFlagFromInputVal()},destroy:function(){this.countryInput.off(this.ns),this.selectedFlagInner.parent().off(this.ns),this.countryInput.parent().before(this.countryInput).remove()}},n.fn[s]=function(i){var t=arguments;if(i===a||"object"==typeof i)return this.each(function(){n.data(this,"plugin_"+s)||n.data(this,"plugin_"+s,new e(this,i))});if("string"==typeof i&&"_"!==i[0]&&"init"!==i){var o;return this.each(function(){var a=n.data(this,"plugin_"+s);a instanceof e&&"function"==typeof a[i]&&(o=a[i].apply(a,Array.prototype.slice.call(t,1))),"destroy"===i&&n.data(this,"plugin_"+s,null)}),o!==a?o:this}},n.fn[s].getCountryData=function(){return h},n.fn[s].setCountryData=function(n){h=n};var h=n.each([{n:"Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)",i:"af"},{n:"Åland Islands (Åland)",i:"ax"},{n:"Albania (Shqipëri)",i:"al"},{n:"Algeria (‫الجزائر‬‎)",i:"dz"},{n:"American Samoa",i:"as"},{n:"Andorra",i:"ad"},{n:"Angola",i:"ao"},{n:"Anguilla",i:"ai"},{n:"Antigua and Barbuda",i:"ag"},{n:"Argentina",i:"ar"},{n:"Armenia (Հայաստան)",i:"am"},{n:"Aruba",i:"aw"},{n:"Australia",i:"au"},{n:"Austria (Österreich)",i:"at"},{n:"Azerbaijan (Azərbaycan)",i:"az"},{n:"Bahamas",i:"bs"},{n:"Bahrain (‫البحرين‬‎)",i:"bh"},{n:"Bangladesh (বাংলাদেশ)",i:"bd"},{n:"Barbados",i:"bb"},{n:"Belarus (Беларусь)",i:"by"},{n:"Belgium (België)",i:"be"},{n:"Belize",i:"bz"},{n:"Benin (Bénin)",i:"bj"},{n:"Bermuda",i:"bm"},{n:"Bhutan (འབྲུག)",i:"bt"},{n:"Bolivia",i:"bo"},{n:"Bosnia and Herzegovina (Босна и Херцеговина)",i:"ba"},{n:"Botswana",i:"bw"},{n:"Brazil (Brasil)",i:"br"},{n:"British Indian Ocean Territory",i:"io"},{n:"British Virgin Islands",i:"vg"},{n:"Brunei",i:"bn"},{n:"Bulgaria (България)",i:"bg"},{n:"Burkina Faso",i:"bf"},{n:"Burundi (Uburundi)",i:"bi"},{n:"Cambodia (កម្ពុជា)",i:"kh"},{n:"Cameroon (Cameroun)",i:"cm"},{n:"Canada",i:"ca"},{n:"Cape Verde (Kabu Verdi)",i:"cv"},{n:"Caribbean Netherlands",i:"bq"},{n:"Cayman Islands",i:"ky"},{n:"Central African Republic (République Centrafricaine)",i:"cf"},{n:"Chad (Tchad)",i:"td"},{n:"Chile",i:"cl"},{n:"China (中国)",i:"cn"},{n:"Christmas Island",i:"cx"},{n:"Cocos (Keeling) Islands (Kepulauan Cocos (Keeling))",i:"cc"},{n:"Colombia",i:"co"},{n:"Comoros (‫جزر القمر‬‎)",i:"km"},{n:"Congo (DRC) (Jamhuri ya Kidemokrasia ya Kongo)",i:"cd"},{n:"Congo (Republic) (Congo-Brazzaville)",i:"cg"},{n:"Cook Islands",i:"ck"},{n:"Costa Rica",i:"cr"},{n:"Côte d’Ivoire",i:"ci"},{n:"Croatia (Hrvatska)",i:"hr"},{n:"Cuba",i:"cu"},{n:"Curaçao",i:"cw"},{n:"Cyprus (Κύπρος)",i:"cy"},{n:"Czech Republic (Česká republika)",i:"cz"},{n:"Denmark (Danmark)",i:"dk"},{n:"Djibouti",i:"dj"},{n:"Dominica",i:"dm"},{n:"Dominican Republic (República Dominicana)",i:"do"},{n:"Ecuador",i:"ec"},{n:"Egypt (‫مصر‬‎)",i:"eg"},{n:"El Salvador",i:"sv"},{n:"Equatorial Guinea (Guinea Ecuatorial)",i:"gq"},{n:"Eritrea",i:"er"},{n:"Estonia (Eesti)",i:"ee"},{n:"Ethiopia",i:"et"},{n:"Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)",i:"fk"},{n:"Faroe Islands (Føroyar)",i:"fo"},{n:"Fiji",i:"fj"},{n:"Finland (Suomi)",i:"fi"},{n:"France",i:"fr"},{n:"French Guiana (Guyane française)",i:"gf"},{n:"French Polynesia (Polynésie française)",i:"pf"},{n:"Gabon",i:"ga"},{n:"Gambia",i:"gm"},{n:"Georgia (საქართველო)",i:"ge"},{n:"Germany (Deutschland)",i:"de"},{n:"Ghana (Gaana)",i:"gh"},{n:"Gibraltar",i:"gi"},{n:"Greece (Ελλάδα)",i:"gr"},{n:"Greenland (Kalaallit Nunaat)",i:"gl"},{n:"Grenada",i:"gd"},{n:"Guadeloupe",i:"gp"},{n:"Guam",i:"gu"},{n:"Guatemala",i:"gt"},{n:"Guernsey",i:"gg"},{n:"Guinea (Guinée)",i:"gn"},{n:"Guinea-Bissau (Guiné Bissau)",i:"gw"},{n:"Guyana",i:"gy"},{n:"Haiti",i:"ht"},{n:"Honduras",i:"hn"},{n:"Hong Kong (香港)",i:"hk"},{n:"Hungary (Magyarország)",i:"hu"},{n:"Iceland (Ísland)",i:"is"},{n:"India (भारत)",i:"in"},{n:"Indonesia",i:"id"},{n:"Iran (‫ایران‬‎)",i:"ir"},{n:"Iraq (‫العراق‬‎)",i:"iq"},{n:"Ireland",i:"ie"},{n:"Isle of Man",i:"im"},{n:"Israel (‫ישראל‬‎)",i:"il"},{n:"Italy (Italia)",i:"it"},{n:"Jamaica",i:"jm"},{n:"Japan (日本)",i:"jp"},{n:"Jersey",i:"je"},{n:"Jordan (‫الأردن‬‎)",i:"jo"},{n:"Kazakhstan (Казахстан)",i:"kz"},{n:"Kenya",i:"ke"},{n:"Kiribati",i:"ki"},{n:"Kosovo (Kosovë)",i:"xk"},{n:"Kuwait (‫الكويت‬‎)",i:"kw"},{n:"Kyrgyzstan (Кыргызстан)",i:"kg"},{n:"Laos (ລາວ)",i:"la"},{n:"Latvia (Latvija)",i:"lv"},{n:"Lebanon (‫لبنان‬‎)",i:"lb"},{n:"Lesotho",i:"ls"},{n:"Liberia",i:"lr"},{n:"Libya (‫ليبيا‬‎)",i:"ly"},{n:"Liechtenstein",i:"li"},{n:"Lithuania (Lietuva)",i:"lt"},{n:"Luxembourg",i:"lu"},{n:"Macau (澳門)",i:"mo"},{n:"Macedonia (FYROM) (Македонија)",i:"mk"},{n:"Madagascar (Madagasikara)",i:"mg"},{n:"Malawi",i:"mw"},{n:"Malaysia",i:"my"},{n:"Maldives",i:"mv"},{n:"Mali",i:"ml"},{n:"Malta",i:"mt"},{n:"Marshall Islands",i:"mh"},{n:"Martinique",i:"mq"},{n:"Mauritania (‫موريتانيا‬‎)",i:"mr"},{n:"Mauritius (Moris)",i:"mu"},{n:"Mayotte",i:"yt"},{n:"Mexico (México)",i:"mx"},{n:"Micronesia",i:"fm"},{n:"Moldova (Republica Moldova)",i:"md"},{n:"Monaco",i:"mc"},{n:"Mongolia (Монгол)",i:"mn"},{n:"Montenegro (Crna Gora)",i:"me"},{n:"Montserrat",i:"ms"},{n:"Morocco (‫المغرب‬‎)",i:"ma"},{n:"Mozambique (Moçambique)",i:"mz"},{n:"Myanmar (Burma) (မြန်မာ)",i:"mm"},{n:"Namibia (Namibië)",i:"na"},{n:"Nauru",i:"nr"},{n:"Nepal (नेपाल)",i:"np"},{n:"Netherlands (Nederland)",i:"nl"},{n:"New Caledonia (Nouvelle-Calédonie)",i:"nc"},{n:"New Zealand",i:"nz"},{n:"Nicaragua",i:"ni"},{n:"Niger (Nijar)",i:"ne"},{n:"Nigeria",i:"ng"},{n:"Niue",i:"nu"},{n:"Norfolk Island",i:"nf"},{n:"North Korea (조선 민주주의 인민 공화국)",i:"kp"},{n:"Northern Mariana Islands",i:"mp"},{n:"Norway (Norge)",i:"no"},{n:"Oman (‫عُمان‬‎)",i:"om"},{n:"Pakistan (‫پاکستان‬‎)",i:"pk"},{n:"Palau",i:"pw"},{n:"Palestine (‫فلسطين‬‎)",i:"ps"},{n:"Panama (Panamá)",i:"pa"},{n:"Papua New Guinea",i:"pg"},{n:"Paraguay",i:"py"},{n:"Peru (Perú)",i:"pe"},{n:"Philippines",i:"ph"},{n:"Pitcairn Islands",i:"pn"},{n:"Poland (Polska)",i:"pl"},{n:"Portugal",i:"pt"},{n:"Puerto Rico",i:"pr"},{n:"Qatar (‫قطر‬‎)",i:"qa"},{n:"Réunion (La Réunion)",i:"re"},{n:"Romania (România)",i:"ro"},{n:"Russia (Россия)",i:"ru"},{n:"Rwanda",i:"rw"},{n:"Saint Barthélemy (Saint-Barthélemy)",i:"bl"},{n:"Saint Helena",i:"sh"},{n:"Saint Kitts and Nevis",i:"kn"},{n:"Saint Lucia",i:"lc"},{n:"Saint Martin (Saint-Martin (partie française))",i:"mf"},{n:"Saint Pierre and Miquelon (Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon)",i:"pm"},{n:"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",i:"vc"},{n:"Samoa",i:"ws"},{n:"San Marino",i:"sm"},{n:"São Tomé and Príncipe (São Tomé e Príncipe)",i:"st"},{n:"Saudi Arabia (‫المملكة العربية السعودية‬‎)",i:"sa"},{n:"Senegal (Sénégal)",i:"sn"},{n:"Serbia (Србија)",i:"rs"},{n:"Seychelles",i:"sc"},{n:"Sierra Leone",i:"sl"},{n:"Singapore",i:"sg"},{n:"Sint Maarten",i:"sx"},{n:"Slovakia (Slovensko)",i:"sk"},{n:"Slovenia (Slovenija)",i:"si"},{n:"Solomon Islands",i:"sb"},{n:"Somalia (Soomaaliya)",i:"so"},{n:"South Africa",i:"za"},{n:"South Georgia & South Sandwich Islands",i:"gs"},{n:"South Korea (대한민국)",i:"kr"},{n:"South Sudan (‫جنوب السودان‬‎)",i:"ss"},{n:"Spain (España)",i:"es"},{n:"Sri Lanka (ශ්‍රී ලංකාව)",i:"lk"},{n:"Sudan (‫السودان‬‎)",i:"sd"},{n:"Suriname",i:"sr"},{n:"Svalbard and Jan Mayen (Svalbard og Jan Mayen)",i:"sj"},{n:"Swaziland",i:"sz"},{n:"Sweden (Sverige)",i:"se"},{n:"Switzerland (Schweiz)",i:"ch"},{n:"Syria (‫سوريا‬‎)",i:"sy"},{n:"Taiwan (台灣)",i:"tw"},{n:"Tajikistan",i:"tj"},{n:"Tanzania",i:"tz"},{n:"Thailand (ไทย)",i:"th"},{n:"Timor-Leste",i:"tl"},{n:"Togo",i:"tg"},{n:"Tokelau",i:"tk"},{n:"Tonga",i:"to"},{n:"Trinidad and Tobago",i:"tt"},{n:"Tunisia (‫تونس‬‎)",i:"tn"},{n:"Turkey (Türkiye)",i:"tr"},{n:"Turkmenistan",i:"tm"},{n:"Turks and Caicos Islands",i:"tc"},{n:"Tuvalu",i:"tv"},{n:"Uganda",i:"ug"},{n:"Ukraine (Україна)",i:"ua"},{n:"United Arab Emirates (‫الإمارات العربية المتحدة‬‎)",i:"ae"},{n:"United Kingdom",i:"gb"},{n:"United States",i:"us"},{n:"U.S. Minor Outlying Islands",i:"um"},{n:"U.S. Virgin Islands",i:"vi"},{n:"Uruguay",i:"uy"},{n:"Uzbekistan (Oʻzbekiston)",i:"uz"},{n:"Vanuatu",i:"vu"},{n:"Vatican City (Città del Vaticano)",i:"va"},{n:"Venezuela",i:"ve"},{n:"Vietnam (Việt Nam)",i:"vn"},{n:"Wallis and Futuna",i:"wf"},{n:"Western Sahara (‫الصحراء الغربية‬‎)",i:"eh"},{n:"Yemen (‫اليمن‬‎)",i:"ye"},{n:"Zambia",i:"zm"},{n:"Zimbabwe",i:"zw"},{n:"",i:"xx"}],function(n,i){i.name=i.n,i.iso2=i.i,delete i.n,delete i.i})});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks zer00ne , It works Perfectly. looking for the same.